# Crash When Using Arrays.fill

Tags: java, arrays, crash

I have a school project that I'm working, where I fill two small arrays with data. To do this I used java.util's Arrays.fill method, which after about ten seconds would cause java to completely crash.

It was simple to fix once I pinpointed the problem by commenting out code until it worked, but I would like to know what actually caused java crash.

I tried to reproduce the crash in a smaller project, but I could not do so. So instead I've included an archive with the project in it.

I'm running lubuntu 14.04.2 x86, and the crash happens under both Oracle JDK 7.76 and Oracle JDK 8.40.

The program fails with this message, the output files are included in the archive:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6dd9d37, pid=4458, tid=2236009280
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b25) (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x653d37]  PhaseIdealLoop::match_fill_loop(IdealLoopTree*, Node*&, Node*&, Node*&, Node*&)+0x257
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Download link to the the archive:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmv8xe82cwn15dg/JavaCrash.tar.gz?dl=1

So, could somebody explain what is going on? Is it my fault, or is it something out of my control?

Comment: What's DLib.Dconsole? Is it a JNI library or native Java? Is it homebrewed, supplied by your school, commercial, or public domain?

Comment: It is a library supplied by my high-school teacher to make graphics easier on kids. It is a wrapper for swing.

Comment: The problem is with whatever native library you're using in your project. The error lists the problematic frame as `PhaseIdealLoop::match_fill_loop`, which is likely an uninitialized pointer being used in that function.

Comment: Any chance it's buggy and uses JNI?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is buggy, I don't have access to the sources.

Comment: I'll bet if you take out the 3 calls to `dc` in the top of the function, it won't crash. Perhaps you're passing out-of-bounds values to the `fillRect` function. Tip-toe around / dance with the native `Dlib` library and I'll bet the crashing behavior will change and/or go away.

Comment: I am able to stop the program from crashing by removing the Arrays.fill calls, and instead doing it manually, so I don't think it is the DConsole's fault. Though when I look at the util.Arrays source [Here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java/?v=source), it looks the same as what I'm doing?

Comment: You don't understand how crashes really work at this level. Buggy code sets off a time bomb; normal code trips and causes the crash. And worse, *other* slightly different normal code does not trip because it doesn't walk onto that bomb. If you're not willing to work with the suggestion, I can't possibly help you.

Comment: Alight, thanks for the suggestions, Ill then tiptoe as you say around and find something that works. Do you know of any resources to learn more about how java crashed do? I really would like to learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72439/discussion-between-basezen-and-ps13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edit see comment) This turned out to be a bug in the JVM 8 rev. 40, released only 3 days ago. DCom library is simply a pure Java Swing wrapper.

On Mac OS JVM 6, no crash; on the same Linux machine with JVM 6, no crash. It happens. OP will attempt a report.

Comment: I got it to crash under Java 8 on Mac too, after controlling the game for about 30 seconds, repeatably. Similar but not exact crash location. (Java 6 runtime allows it to run several minutes, never any issues.) So given it was released 3 days ago, cutting edge is bleeding edge.